# How to get the duration of a SCHEDULED headline in minutes

Tags: org-mode

How can I get the duration of a scheduled headline in minutes? As an example, I'd expect the following heading to return `65`.

```
* Foo
  SCHEDULED: <2023-11-19 Sun 10:00-11:05>
```

**What I've tried**

1. `org-get-scheduled-time` returns the start time as an `org-mode` time tuple. However, this doesn't include the end time.

Comment: Re: `org-get-scheduled-time` returning only the start time - that's because `SCHEDULED` does not imply duration in Org mode. It is only to notify you that you are supposed to *start* working on something at the indicated date (and possibly time). See [Deadlines and Scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html) in the Org mode manual - particularly the note marked `Important`. As far as Org mode is concerned, it needs to know the start time in order to add the event to the agenda. If you have the grid turned on, a timestamp like the above shows the duration as well...

Comment: ... but that's incidental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that takes a timestamp range as argument and calculates its duration in minutes:

```el
(defun my/org-timestamp-range-duration-in-minutes (ts)
   (if (member (org-element-property :type ts) '(active-range inactive-range))
       (/ (time-subtract (org-timestamp-to-time ts 'end) (org-timestamp-to-time ts)) 60)
     nil))
```

We take a [timestamp object](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html#orgcf4d47e) as argument, check that it's a time range (active or inactive), convert the start and end times to internal format, subtract the start time from the end time which returns seconds and divide by 60 to convert to minutes.

If you want to find out the duration of some timestamp range in your Org mode file, use the following invocation with `point` at the beginning of the timestamp (i.e. the opening `<` or `[` for an active or inactive timestamp resp.):

```el
M-: (my/org-timestamp-range-duration-in-minutes (org-element-timestamp-parser))
```

E.g. in the following Org mode file, when I run the code block, it moves `point` to the beginning of the timestamp (previously determined to be 12 by using `C-u C-x =`) and then uses the above invocation to calculate the duration of the timestamp range in minutes:

```org
* APPT foo
<2023-11-22 Wed 20:00-21:00>


* Code
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/org-timestamp-range-duration-in-minutes (ts)
    (if (member (org-element-property :type ts) '(active-range inactive-range))
        (/ (time-subtract (org-timestamp-to-time ts 'end) (org-timestamp-to-time ts)) 60)
      nil))

  (save-excursion
    (goto-char 12)
    (my/org-timestamp-range-duration-in-minutes (org-element-timestamp-parser)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
60
:end:
```

If you change the 12 to some other point in the buffer (e.g. 13), the type check fails and the function returns `nil`. If you change the timestamp at position 12 to e.g. `<2023-11-22 Wed 20:00>` (i.e. not a range), the type check fails there as well. Ranges with different dates work fine: e.g. if you change it to `<2023-11-22 Wed 20:00>--<2023-11-23 Thu 21:00>` the block gives a result of 1500 minutes (= 25 hours).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem optimal and it assumes the timestamp is formatted as `<YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM-HH:MM .*>`.

```
(defun summarize-agenda-time--get-scheduled-duration-in-minutes (pos)
  "Return the scheduled duration, in minutes, of the heading at POS, or nil."
  (let ((timestamp (org-entry-get pos "SCHEDULED")))
    (when timestamp
      (let ((timestamp-with-duration-regexp "\\(<.*\\)\\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\\)-\\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\\)\\(.*>\\)"))
        (when (string-match timestamp-with-duration-regexp
                            timestamp)
          (let* ((start-org-time (org-time-string-to-time
                                  (replace-regexp-in-string timestamp-with-duration-regexp
                                                            "\\1\\2\\4"
                                                            timestamp)))
                 (end-org-time (org-time-string-to-time
                                (replace-regexp-in-string timestamp-with-duration-regexp
                                                          "\\1\\3\\4"
                                                          timestamp))))
            (/ (org-time-subtract end-org-time
                                  start-org-time)
               60)))))))
```

Comment: I think you should write a function that takes a timestamp range as argument and calculates the duration of it in minutes. You should avoid tying it to a keyword (like `SCHEDULED`) since time stamp ranges occur in many contexts (and `SCHEDULED` is not - or at least should not be - one of those contexts; see my comment to your question).